# how to track down security problems between IIS web servers?

Tags: web-server, iis-6, iis-8, credentials

The new version of our website is built on a Windows 2012 server.

We are having a problem that it cannot display pdf reports that are stored on another server which is running Windows Server 2003

How could I track down if there is a credentials or security problem preventing our windows 2012 web server with IIS8 from connecting properly?

The old version of the web server (which is live for hundreds of clients) is running fine with no issues and that's an old Win 2003 Server box running IIS 6

I have tried looking at the IIS logs on both servers and and cannot see anything that stands out (such as looking for the IP address of the client etc.)

Both servers are on the same domain, except the old report server is called www.domain.com and the new IIS web server is (temporarily) called www2012.domain.com

Answer (score 1):

Are your IIS running under a domain?
What are your configuration settings for the sites?
Are those configurations matching?
Is anonymous authentication disabled?
Are you impersonating the account used to open the PDFs ?

You need to ensure that the authentication settings for the sites are matching, also if you are using windows authentication and your application pool is impersonating a user, make sure that account has privileges on the server it needs to access.

Comment: thanks, we are running IIS under a domain, config settings should be the same, but that's being checked by the infrastructure team......